# Custom Action on trip animation widget

Tags: thingsboard

Can you get the custom action to update the dashboard? I am having a similar problem with the trip animation widget. I've configured custom actions to change the label function and cpolor point functions, but they only work when the widget is in a play state on the sliderbar. I cannot see a way of initiating these functions when the datasources are updated in a custom widget, without pressing the play button.

Comment: You need to provide more info. For instance, what is the dashboard you're referring to? What is the trip animation widget? etc

Answer (score 0):

ThingsBoard came back to me and gave the next solution:

```
widgetContext.defaultSubscription.onLatestDataUpdated();
widgetContext.defaultSubscription.onDataUpdated();
```

It works perfectly on the trip animation widget, and reruns the widget functions with parameters given in the custom action.